# How do I add npm packages into visual studio 2019 with .net core project?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, npm

I am using react for front end along with .net core in backend. I am told to to use visual studio 2019 to work with .net core and this is the first time I am using visual studio. I installed react + redux template and I am wondering how can I add npm packages such as `react-table` or `@material-ui/core` in my project ? Can I just straight add to `dependencies` inside package.json file like `"@material-ui/core": "version"` and will it automatically install when I save ? And also how do I uninstall npm packages as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install npm packages into your project just simply use

```
npm install <package name>
```

To uninstall you use

```
npm uninstall <package name>
```

You need to use these commands within the terminal.
You can open a integrated terminal window in vscode:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

Comment: Do you know where should I go to have a terminal to type `npm install <package name>` in vs 2019 ? In vs code, ctrl + ` pop up a terminal

Comment: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudioNowIncludesAnIntegratedTerminal.aspx

Comment: Has this been answered because I am getting "The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program." in the "Developer PowerShell" console window